# After taking a picture, the app crashes when going to preview xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, camera, xamarin.android, preview

I am trying to have my app take a picture then show it after it has been saved to the phone.

So far it takes the picture, it saves it in my directory(as i can see it if i look after), but when it goes to show in the preview it stops working.

I have narrowed it down to the line as well. in the `OnActivityResult` where *request code == 1034* this line crashes it.

```
Uri uri = data.Data;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.fragment_layout);

        //camera button
        FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.camera).Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            String[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };

            using (var dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
            {
                dialogBuilder.SetTitle("Add Photo");
                dialogBuilder.SetItems(items, (d, arg) =>
                {
                    //Take photo
                    if (arg.Which == 0)
                    {
                        captureImage();
                    }
                    //Choose from gallery
                    else if (arg.Which == 1)
                    {
                        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
                        intent.SetType("image/*");
                        this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
                    }
                });

                dialogBuilder.Show();
            };

        };
    }



    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            if (requestCode == 1034)
            {
                // Handle the newly captured image
                var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.foodPreview);
                Uri uri = data.Data;
                imageView.SetImageURI(uri);

            }
            else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            {
                // Handle the image chosen from gallery
                var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.foodPreview);
                Uri uri = data.Data;
                imageView.SetImageURI(uri);
            }
        }
}
```

The uri is using Android.Net, and I have camera and read/write external storge in my android manifest.

My error log is

> 07-15 12:41:47.088 D/Mono    (16481): Searching for
>   'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'. 07-15 12:41:47.088 D/Mono
>   (16481): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'. 07-15
>   12:41:47.088 D/Mono    (16481): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_new_object_array'. 07-15 12:41:47.088 D/Mono
>   (16481): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)'). 07-15
>   12:41:47.088 D/Mono    (16481): Searching for
>   'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'. 07-15 12:41:47.088
>   D/Mono    (16481): Probing
>   'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'. 07-15 12:41:47.088
>   D/Mono    (16481): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_set_object_array_element'. 07-15 12:41:47.098
>   D/Mono    (16481): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
>   07-15 12:41:47.098 D/Mono    (16481): Searching for
>   'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'. 07-15 12:41:47.098
>   D/Mono    (16481): Probing
>   'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'. 07-15 12:41:47.098
>   D/Mono    (16481): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_get_object_array_element'. 07-15 12:41:47.118
>   D/AbsListView(16481): Get MotionRecognitionManager 07-15 12:41:48.859
>   D/Mono    (16481): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
>   07-15 12:41:48.859 D/Mono    (16481): Searching for
>   'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'. 07-15 12:41:48.859 D/Mono
>   (16481): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'. 07-15
>   12:41:48.859 D/Mono    (16481): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'. 07-15 12:41:48.940
>   D/AbsListView(16481): onDetachedFromWindow 07-15 12:41:49.130
>   E/ViewRootImpl(16481): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null 07-15
>   12:41:50.751 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16481): showStatusIcon on
>   inactive InputConnection Thread finished:  #5 07-15
>   12:41:53.675 D/Mono    (16481): [0x6885e7d0] worker finishing The
>   thread 'Unknown' (0x5) has exited with code 0 (0x0). 07-15
>   12:41:57.559 D/AbsListView(16481): onDetachedFromWindow 07-15
>   12:41:57.559 D/AbsListView(16481): onDetachedFromWindow 07-15
>   12:41:57.659 D/AbsListView(16481): Get MotionRecognitionManager 07-15
>   12:41:57.669 D/AbsListView(16481): Get MotionRecognitionManager
>   Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> 07-15 12:42:06.528 D/Mono    (16481): DllImport attempting to load:
>   '/system/lib/liblog.so'. 07-15 12:42:06.528 D/Mono    (16481):
>   DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'. 07-15 12:42:06.528
>   D/Mono    (16481): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so'
>   ('/system/lib/liblog.so'). 07-15 12:42:06.528 D/Mono    (16481):
>   Searching for '__android_log_print'. 07-15 12:42:06.528 D/Mono
>   (16481): Probing '__android_log_print'. 07-15 12:42:06.528 D/Mono
>   (16481): Found as '__android_log_print'. 07-15 12:42:06.538
>   I/MonoDroid(16481): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 07-15 12:42:06.538
>   I/MonoDroid(16481): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. 07-15 12:42:06.538
>   I/MonoDroid(16481):   at
>   BitesBoardMobile.Droid.MainActivity.OnActivityResult (Int32
>   requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) [0x0002d]
>   in C:\Users\Larry\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\BitesBoardMobile\BitesBoardMobile\BitesBoardMobile.Droid\MainActivity.cs:204
>   07-15 12:42:06.538 I/MonoDroid(16481):   at
>   Android.App.Activity.n_OnActivityResult_IILandroid_content_Intent_
>   (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, Int32 requestCode, Int32
>   native_resultCode, IntPtr native_data) [0x00014] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/ffca580c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2150
>   07-15 12:42:06.538 I/MonoDroid(16481):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:94390831-eca3-413f-9213-15bb3ef4a181
>   (intptr,intptr,int,int,intptr) 07-15 12:42:06.578 D/Mono    (16481):
>   DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)'). 07-15 12:42:06.578
>   D/Mono    (16481): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'. 07-15
>   12:42:06.578 D/Mono    (16481): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
>   07-15 12:42:06.578 D/Mono    (16481): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_throw'. An unhandled exception occured.
>
> 07-15 12:42:09.542 E/mono    (16481):  07-15 12:42:09.542 E/mono
>   (16481): Unhandled Exception: 07-15 12:42:09.542 E/mono    (16481):
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. 07-15 12:42:09.542 E/mono    (16481):   at (wrapper
>   dynamic-method) System.Object:94390831-eca3-413f-9213-15bb3ef4a181
>   (intptr,intptr,int,int,intptr) 07-15 12:42:09.542 E/mono    (16481):
>   at (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   System.Object:94390831-eca3-413f-9213-15bb3ef4a181
>   (intptr,intptr,int,int,intptr) 07-15 12:42:09.542 E/mono-rt (16481):
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 07-15
>   12:42:09.542 E/mono-rt (16481):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:94390831-eca3-413f-9213-15bb3ef4a181
>   (intptr,intptr,int,int,intptr) 07-15 12:42:09.542 E/mono-rt (16481):
>   at (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   System.Object:94390831-eca3-413f-9213-15bb3ef4a181
>   (intptr,intptr,int,int,intptr) In mgmain JNI_OnLoad

Please help.

Comment: Post the Exception / stack trace that you are getting

Comment: how do i get that off my phone?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-device/

Comment: So it is an object not set to a reference, i just dont see how it not set.